# Whats wrong with my code Laravel Callback function GroupBy Month

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-4.2, function-query

Im going to count my pallet_condition 0,1,2,3 and group it by month 
but i always got an error like this please help whats wrong with my code.
something wrong with my date_format?

My Error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in group statement is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `liip_psrm` inner join `liip_psrm_items` on `liip_psrm`.`id` = `liip_psrm_items`.`psrm_items_id` where date(`liip_psrm_items`.`created_at`) >= 2018-10-09 and date(`liip_psrm_items`.`created_at`) <= 2019-01-31 and `liip_psrm`.`status` = 0 and `liip_psrm`.`customer_id` = 14 and `pallet_condition` = 0 group by WEEK(created_at) order by WEEK(created_at) asc)
```

My Callback function

```
$problem_condition_computations = function($condition) use ($psrm_maintenance, $start, $end, $customers){
        return DB::table('liip_psrm')
        ->join('liip_psrm_items', 'liip_psrm.id', '=', 'liip_psrm_items.psrm_items_id')
        ->whereDate('liip_psrm_items.created_at', '>=', $start)
        ->whereDate('liip_psrm_items.created_at', '<=', $end)
        ->select(
                DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(liip_psrm_items.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates
                "))
                ->where('liip_psrm.status','=', 0)
                ->where('liip_psrm.customer_id','=',$customers)
                ->where('pallet_condition', $condition)
                ->groupBy('dates')   
                ->count();
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

"dates" field you are using in groupBy is alias name, So it do not identifying it and not working as you are expecting.

Same as you used in Select

```
DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(liip_psrm_items.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates")
```

Put it in GroupBy 
& It will work.

Hope, It will help, Let me know if you still find difficulties.

Comment: You are welcome! please check it as correct answer then!